# Kendo UI Grid Row Template Grid with calling Javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I am messing around with Kendo UI. I am trying to add some javascript code in the template and the grid does't render.

Here is the Row Template Code:

```
        <script id="dlRowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
            <tr>
                <td class="details">
                   <span class="title"><a href="#: link#">#: title#</a></span>
                   <span class="description">Airdate: #: airdate#</span>
                </td>
                <td class="ID">
                  <a onClick="OpenInNewTab('url=#: modifiedtext#')">DL NZB</a>
                </td>
           </tr>
        </script>
        <script id="altdlRowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
            <tr>
                <td class="details">
                   <span class="title"><a href="#: link#">#: title#</a></span>
                   <span class="description">Airdate: #: airdate#</span>
                </td>
                <td class="ID">
                  <a onClick="OpenInNewTab('http://url=#: modifiedtext#')">DL NZB</a>
                </td>
           </tr>
        </script>
```

Here is the Table HTML Code

```
            <table id="dl_grid">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="details"/>
                    <col />
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Details
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            </table>
```

Here is the code setting up the grid in  tags

```
    $("#dl_grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: "include/showstuff.php"
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data"
            }
        },
        rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#dlRowTemplate").html()),
        altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#altdlRowTemplate").html()),
        height: 430
    });
```

The data is called when a push a button and calls a php page to grab the data (in  tags):

```
    $("#view").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var textVal = $("#cmb").val();
        var dynamicURL = "include/showstuff.php?id=" + textVal; 
        var grid = $("#dl_grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = dynamicURL;
        grid.dataSource.read();
    });
```

Thanks in advance.